# How to retrieve Multi Value Lookup List using SharePoint 2013 REST Api

Tags: 2013, rest

I have a Blog subsite of my main website. I am trying to get the Top 2 blog posts along with the number of comments and actual comments. I am able to get Number of Comments with the field NumCommentsId but along with it i also want Comments to be part of the JSON object returned from the REST API. This is how my url looks like:

```
http://mywebsite-dev/blog/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Posts')/items?$select=Title,Body,Id,LikesCount,NumCommentsId
```

This is how the returned JSON looks like:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(2)",
                    "uri": "http://mywebsite-dev/blog/_api/Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(2)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.PostsListItem"
                },
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Blog 1",
                "Body": "<div class=\"ExternalClass30B2DE63AD2D4EE1AC4DD2735266245C\"><p>This is my blog 1•</p></div>",
                "NumCommentsId": 0,
                "LikesCount": null,
                "ID": 2
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(3)",
                    "uri": "http://mywebsite-dev/blog/_api/Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(3)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.PostsListItem"
                },
                "Id": 3,
                "Title": "Blog 2",
                "Body": "<div class=\"ExternalClass9FDE8E9403FF43F3BEE2BC24798EDA16\"><p>This is second cloud blog•</p></div>",
                "NumCommentsId": 3,
                "LikesCount": null,
                "ID": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want actual comments to be returned in this JSON object. Something like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(2)",
                    "uri": "http://mywebsite-dev/blog/_api/Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(2)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.PostsListItem"
                },
                "Id": 2,
                "Title": "Blog 1",
                "Body": "<div class=\"ExternalClass30B2DE63AD2D4EE1AC4DD2735266245C\"><p>This is my blog 1•</p></div>",
                "NumCommentsId": 0,
        "Comments":{}
                "LikesCount": null,
                "ID": 2
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(3)",
                    "uri": "http://mywebsite-dev/blog/_api/Web/Lists(guid'862870c0-e56b-48ca-9da4-b337d05984aa')/Items(3)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.PostsListItem"
                },
                "Id": 3,
                "Title": "Blog 2",
                "Body": "<div class=\"ExternalClass9FDE8E9403FF43F3BEE2BC24798EDA16\"><p>This is second cloud blog•</p></div>",
                "NumCommentsId": 3,
        "Comments":[
                {
                "Id":1,
                "Title":"My Comment Title",
                "Body":"My Comment Body"
                },
                {
                "Id":2,
                "Title":"My second Comment Title",
                "Body":"My second Comment Body"
                },

                {
                "Id":3,
                "Title":"My third Comment Title",
                "Body":"My third Comment Body"
                },
               ]
                "LikesCount": null,
                "ID": 3
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I took a look and, based on the way the lookup fields are implemented, I'm pretty sure you can't get the posts and the comments with a single REST API call.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible with REST API.

Query for multi-value lookup fields
Because multi-value lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection4